# Preventing a page from being opened in a second tab

Tags: javascript, python, django, security

In a Django web application that I'm developing, I have a particular page that should be allowed to be refreshed, but not be opened in a new tab. How do I do this?

Note: Currently, I have a unique UUID rendered on the page as a hidden element, and it gets regenerated for each GET request. This way, I am able to currently detect each unique request to that page.